# How to specify multiple paths from CLI for Webpack's devServer.contentBase option

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

The Webpack [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-contentbase) for `devServer.contentBase` says

> It is also possible to serve from multiple directories:

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    contentBase: [path.join(__dirname, 'public'), path.join(__dirname, 'assets')]
  }
};
```

**Usage via the CLI**

```
webpack-dev-server --content-base /path/to/content/dir
```

I don't know how to pass multiple paths via CLI.

In my **package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server --content-base dist"

  },
```

I tried passing following values for `start:dev` command but none of them worked.

```
webpack-dev-server --content-base dist src/css
webpack-dev-server --content-base dist, src/css
webpack-dev-server --content-base 'dist src/css'
webpack-dev-server --content-base 'dist', 'src/css'
webpack-dev-server --content-base [ 'dist', 'src/css' ]
```

I found one related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26259276/936494) but couldn't figure out the solution.

Also is there any standard being followed which specifies how an argument accepting an array of values should be specified on command-line? If yes then please provide a reference to that.

Comment: I just checked the [source code of webpack-dev-server](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/0b89fd94b78f6e049614ab466a7eab7d6a2a33f2/bin/webpack-dev-server.js#L188) it has something to check for arrays. I passed an array in Powershell but it didn't work. Try it with you shell may it works!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out looking at the following [source code](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/bin/webpack-dev-server.js#L188) snippet

```
if (Array.isArray(options.contentBase)) {
   options.contentBase = options.contentBase.map((p) => path.resolve(p));
 }
```

We need to pass multiple `--content-base` arguments in following manner

```
"webpack-dev-server --content-base dist --content-base src/css"
```

Thanks to the source code hint provided by **Ali Doustkani** in his comment to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the paths in an array.

```
devServer: {
  static: [
    path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    path.join(__dirname, 'assets'),
  ],
}
```

With that you don't need `--content-base` anymore.